# Getting multiple copies of images when using WP_query to display custom post

Tags: wordpress

I'm using WP-query to display my 3 most recent 'events' which are a custom post type.

Visually it looks like its working fine, but after doing some debugging I noticed that the same image is being loaded 4 times for each post.

```
<div class="container"> 
<?php 
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'projects',
'posts_per_page' => '2'
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 
$count = $the_query->post_count;
?>
 <div class="row small-up-1 medium-up-2 large-up-<?php echo $count ?>"  data-equalizer="news" data-equalize-on-stack="false" data-equalize-on="medium">
  <?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>
  <div class="column">        
   <div class="card">
    <div class="card-divider" data-equalizer-watch="news">
     <h4> <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
     <?php
 // FLEXIBLE CONTENT NAME
 if( have_rows('main_sections') ):
 // FLEXIBLE CONTENT NAME
while ( have_rows('main_sections') ) : the_row(); ?>
 <?php // LAYOUT NAME
if( get_row_layout() == 'standard_details' ): ?>

 <?php if( get_sub_field('date_of_event') ): 
   $field_name1 = "date_of_event";
   $field1 = get_sub_field_object($field_name1);
 ?>
    <p><?php echo $field1['value']; ?></p>
 <?php endif; ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
   <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php the_excerpt(__('(more…)')); ?>
    </div>
    <?php if ( 'video' == get_post_format() ) { ?>
    <div class="video-icon">
    <i class="fa fa-play fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
 <?php } ?>
   <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
     <img data-interchange="[<?php echo the_post_thumbnail_url('recent-news'); ?>, small]" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
    </a>
   </div>      
   </div>    
  <?php 
  endwhile;
  wp_reset_postdata();
  ?>
  </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Use `get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID())` so it will get image url of that particular   ID

Comment: Thanks but that is still resulting in 5 copies of the same image

Comment: just images are same and other info is different? echo `id` to check after image tag to see whether you are getting different id for your events

Comment: not sure I understand.. here is the page ... its the "current project section"http://web.artisan-creative.co.uk/staging/blueyonderevents/

Comment: Its looking exactly how I want it on the site, but the developer tools show the same image loading multiple times which is bloating the loading time

Comment: `data-interchange="[http://web.artisan-creative.co.uk/staging/blueyonderevents/wp-content/uploads/sites/8/2017/07/MR-logo-distressed-350x350.png, small], [http://web.artisan-creative.co.uk/staging/blueyonderevents/wp-content/uploads/sites/8/2017/07/MR-logo-distressed-350x350.png, medium], [http://web.artisan-creative.co.uk/staging/blueyonderevents/wp-content/uploads/sites/8/2017/07/MR-logo-distressed-350x350.png, large], [http://web.artisan-creative.co.uk/staging/blueyonderevents/wp-content/uploads/sites/8/2017/07/MR-logo-distressed-350x350.png, xlarge]"`

Comment: you mean this tag in your console?

Comment: Oh I may have made a school boy error, I thought I’d switched from foundation interchange just to a standard img tag